# How to build a 32-bit deb file on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: 64-bit, compiling, 32-bit, deb

I have followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/28373/364819) to get the build dependencies for what I am building, and then actually compile the source and build it into a deb file, however I am needing to create a deb file for 32-bit, and I am running 64-bit, so it automatically makes it a 64-bit one and not a 32-bit one, so is there any way that I can specify that I want it to create a 32-bit one and not a 64-bit one?

Comment: There is no source package for `qtox` though. I tried `apt-get source qtox`, but it was not able to find a source package.

Comment: maybe related: http://askubuntu.com/q/54988/367990

Comment: `sbuild` would be much easier - you're basically building in a clean chroot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can simply specify the architecture via -a in `debuild`:

```
debuild -a i386
```

Although in most cases that won't work. `pbuilder` is a fantastic tool which provides you with a clean Ubuntu/Debian system inside you environment which you can specify the architecture of.

`man pbuilder` has all the info you need you create your 32-bit archive. Here's a couple of useful commands for you inside `pbuilder`:

```
sudo pbuilder --create --architecture i386
sudo pbuilder --build mypackage.dsc
```

[pbuilder's user manual](https://pbuilder.alioth.debian.org/)