# Unable to compile 32 bit Qt 4.8.6 libraries on 64 bit machine

Tags: 32-bit, qt, openssl

I am trying to build 32 bit Qt 4.8.6 libraries on Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed additional libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libx32gcc-4.8-dev
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5
sudo apt-get install lib32bz2-1.0
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

and after I have made a configuration I run the build:

```
./configure -platform linux-g++-32
make
```

The build crashes with the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:63:0,
             from ssl/qsslsocket_openssl_p.h:66,
             from ssl/qsslsocket_openssl_symbols_p.h:57,
             from ssl/qsslcertificate.cpp:110:
/usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:56:33: fatal error: openssl/opensslconf.h: `No such file or directory`
 #include <openssl/opensslconf.h>
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

I have the newest version of libssl-dev libraries. Please help me to fix this compilation issue.

Comment: You must install 32-bit versions of libraries and their -dev packages, to be able to compile against them.

Comment: Also, you didn't say what version of Ubuntu you are on, but qt4 4.8.6 is already included in Ubuntu 15.04. The current development version also has 4.8.6 for qt4.

Comment: @dobey When I try to install libssl-dev:i386 apt-get gives me the warning: The following packages will be REMOVED:  build-essential dkms g++ g++-multilib gcc gcc-multilib. I installed g++multilib just before qt 4.8.6 compilation. I dont need to remove it.

Comment: Then, I'd suggest creating a 32-bit chroot and compiling it within there, if you really must build 4.8.6 from source for some reason, and installing `libssl-dev:i386` is not satisfactory in terms of dependencies.

Comment: @YuriRudakov: what version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: @Fabby Ubuntu 14.04. I mentioned it in the very first line.

Comment: Sorry, missed that...  +1 for my mistake and a good question.  **;-)**

Comment: which libraries do you mean =)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/657814/367165